# Recommendation Task Evaluation Metrics

Tags: recommendation-engine, evaluation

I am currently engaged in a point of interest recommendation project, utilizing Softmax for predicting class labels. Each data sample is assigned a single label, and I determine the top recommendation by considering the softmax top k probabilities. I want to assess the model's performance using precision and recall at k. These metrics reflect the proportion of recommendations within the top k relevant to the user. Despite lacking user experience data, I seek guidance on calculating accuracy at k and recall at k metrics. I do not have a user experience data (feedbacks).

I just compute the accuracy using basic accuracy formula that is used for classification task